# Receiving multiple messages after sending in group chat using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

after sending a message it is receiving to the group. But at the same time again I'm receiving all the previous messages. Help me out of this.
Here is my code:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
    public void onClick(View view) {
        to = groupname + "@conference.localhost".toString();
        String text = (textMessage.getText().toString());
        textMessage.setText("");

        muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, to);

        try {
            muc.join(USERNAME);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.groupchat);
        msg.setBody(text);
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.sendPacket(msg);
            Msg data = new Msg();
            data.setMessage(text);
            data.setName(userFrom);
            data.setDate(DateAndTime.getCurrentDate());
            data.setTime(DateAndTime.getCurrentTime());
            data.setSender(true);
            MessageListAdapter.messagesItems.add(data);
            notifyMyAdapter();
        }
    }
});
```

and here is my receiving code:

```
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {

    this.connection = connection;
    if(connection != null) {

        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.groupchat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                 Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from " + fromName);
                    Msg data = new Msg();
                    String subject = message.getSubject();

                    if (subject == null) {
                        data.setMessage(message.getBody());
                        data.setName(NAME);
                        data.setDate(DateAndTime.getCurrentDate());
                        data.setTime(DateAndTime.getCurrentTime());
                        data.setSender(false);
                        MessageListAdapter.messagesItems.add(data);

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            notifyMyAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                } else if (subject.equals("")){
                    data.setMessage(message.getBody());
                    data.setName(NAME);
                    data.setDate(DateAndTime.getCurrentDate());
                    data.setTime(DateAndTime.getCurrentTime());
                    data.setSender(false);
                    MessageListAdapter.messagesItems.add(data);
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            notifyMyAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        },filter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MultiUserChat` To control the amount of history to receive while joining a room you will need to provide a configured `DiscussionHistory` object. for more info about `MultiUserChat` [refer this](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html)

```
muc.join(String nickname, String password, DiscussionHistory history, long timeout)
```

where `DiscussionHistory` class controls the number of characters
or messages to receive when entering a room. The room will decide the 
amount of history to return if you don't specify a 
`DiscussionHistory` while joining a room. for more info [refer this](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/DiscussionHistory.html)

Example :

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, to);
DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory(); history.setMaxStanzas(0);
muc.join("username", "password", history, SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());
```